# Connecting to vps via sftp using Filezilla

Tags: ftp, sftp, ftp-client, filezilla

**edit start : some background before my question:**

I used to connect to my vps fine with FileZilla

Now, I did a do-release-upgrade on the server and I can't connect with FileZilla. But I didn't change any parameter in FileZilla on my laptop, so I guess that the problem is coming from my server, but if you think that it is a FileZilla issue and that I'd rather check FileZilla Forum, let me know.

**edit end**

I try to connect to my server using `sftp`. In command line,

```
sftp -P 22 username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

runs fine. But with FileZilla, I get

```
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx" 22
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey wait ! Why Am I getting down voted and almost closed ? Can I have an explanation at least ?

Comment: This is not a question about programming and therefore off topic here.

Comment: Hum... I thought that a question about server configuration could belong here. Am I wrong ? But I agree, if it is a FileZilla issue, I will remove my question.

Comment: There is [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) explaining what belongs here. General software question should go to the http://superuser.com Anyway you already have answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Command:    open "username@xx.xxx.xx.xxx" 22
```

This should be only

```
Command:    open xx.xxx.xx.xxx 22
```

Username is send in later stages and have probably different field in the Filezilla configuration:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ok, the version of FileZilla in the Ubuntu repositories is totally out of date. I realised that with your screen capture. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on which Ubuntu version. The one I have in Ubuntu 16.04 is just fine.

Comment: 14.04 LTS. I added the ppa and upgraded. It works. I'm not familiar with server admin so I thought that it was my fault.